# Converting 'False'(string) to False(boolean) During LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql

In MySQL is there anyway of loading "False" into a boolean column.

While loading data in table having boolean column and where data is in "True" or "False", it gives warning of:

```
"Incorrect integer value: 'False' for column 'c1' at row 1".
```

Table structure is as follow

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `n1` (
  `c1` boolean ,
  `c2` int
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I am using load data statement to load from file "file1" which is comma separated and enclosed in double quotes. Following is the data sample

```
"False","1" 
"True","2"
```

The load data local infile statements is as below

```
load data local infile 'file1' 
into table n1 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
  enclosed by '\"' LINES 
  TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Comment: The earlier post seems to have incorrect subject,so i have removed that and posted this one with more elaboration. If you can suggest about the solution it would be helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convert the first value using user variables to load the True/False values.

Then, compare it to the value 'True'

## PROPOSED SOLUTION

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/bin/input.txt' INTO TABLE n1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (@var1,c2)
SET c1 = (@var1 = 'True');
```

## SAMPLE DATA

```
C:\bin>dir
 Volume in drive C is TI10665200H
 Volume Serial Number is A273-2EFF

 Directory of C:\bin

10/21/2014  10:01 AM    <DIR>          .
10/21/2014  10:01 AM    <DIR>          ..
10/21/2014  10:01 AM                23 input.txt
               1 File(s)             23 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  685,548,244,992 bytes free

C:\bin>type input.txt
"False","1"
"True","2"
C:\bin>
```

## CODE FOR PROPOSED SOLUTION

```
USE test
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS n1;
CREATE TABLE `n1` (
  `c1` boolean ,
  `c2` int
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/bin/input.txt' INTO TABLE n1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (@var1,c2)
SET c1 = (@var1 = 'True');
SELECT * FROM n1;
```

## CODE FOR PROPOSED SOLUTION EXECUTED

```
mysql> USE test
Database changed
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS n1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `n1` (
    ->   `c1` boolean ,
    ->   `c2` int
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.38 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/bin/input.txt' INTO TABLE n1
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (@var1,c2)
    -> SET c1 = (@var1 = 'True');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 2  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM n1;
+------+------+
| c1   | c2   |
+------+------+
|    0 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: It always returns the false condition means 0 even for True fields as well. I executed following statement   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file1' INTO table n1  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' enclosed by '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (@var1,c2) SET c1 = IF(@var='True',1,0);

Comment: I had just removed an extra semicolon. Please try again.

Comment: I executed it after correcting but the problem remains the same. It always returns the false condition values while loading. can you guess why?

Comment: I got it, please look again !!!

Comment: Thank you for accepting. This is has been a headache for years (http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,395223,395223)